# TextField keyboard does not show in capital letters in iOS 11?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextfield

I have a textfield & from storyboard i have set its property to show capital lettres & i have also tried below code.

```
    textFieldOne.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationType.allCharacters
```

But this does not work in iOS 11 but this works fine for iOS 10.

Comment: Are you testing on a real iOS device or in the simulator? If in the simulator, are you typing with your computer's keyboard or using the onscreen keyboard?

Comment: No i am using a real device.In iOS 11 simulator it works fine